# Cannot get the keystore for Android maps API

Tags: java, android, keystore

I've recently tried to access the debug keystore created by the Eclipse SDK in order to use the Google maps API within my application. Now I know the file exists and have its path. However to access it and receive an MD5 fingerprint I have to use a keytool command.

Now I've been told that this command has to be done in the computers command prompt as there is no keytool GUI. And this is where the problem is as my command prompt doesn't recognise the command I'm giving it. Here's the command:

```
keytool -list-alias androiddebugkey-keystore(path_to debug_keystore).keystore-storepass android -keypass android
```

(Brackets should be left and right arrows) to which command prompt replies:

> keytool is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

Now I tried manually entering the path which I
 believe would be (C: \Users\Adam.Android\debug.keystore).keystore I've
 also tried variations of C: \Adam.Android\debug.keystore).keystore
 Adam.Android\debug.keystore).keystore
 .Android\debug.keystore).keystore debug.keystore).keystore

Which it then replies: "the system cannot find the path specified"

So either command prompt doesn't recognise the command "keytool" or I'm entering the path wrong (which is likely as I don't use command prompt commands often enough to know how to write paths successfully).

I also run the `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin` through my command prompt and it replies:

> C: program\ is not reconized as internal or external command

Please help me out.

Comment: If your path contains spaces, use `"`: `"C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose commands/directories that contain spaces (or special characters), with the double qoute **"**

So to run your command, you would use:

```
C:\> "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\keytool" (option parameters)
```

So your complete command should look something like this then:

```
C:\> "C:\Program Files (x86)\java\jre6\bin\keytool.exe" -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\Shazar\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

I've verified it on my system.

Comment: thanks u sir i have made such sily mistake sir if you dont mind would you give me step by step procedure how to get md5 fingerprint for gogle API KEY.sir all just i want to incorporate google map in one of my app plz plz help me as i spent lot ov time on this but i couldnot find any sucees i just want to learn android plz help me out

Comment: Perhaps if you follow the guide in this *Obtaining a Google Maps Android API Key* https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey

Comment: yes sir i did try this many time i followed the tutuorial and got the path of keystore located in eclicpse from Windows > Prefs > Android > Build .than i wrote the this"C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\keytool" command on command promptand it excuted   the keytool option then i wrote this command on my command prompt "keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\Shazar\.android\debug.keystore.keystore -storepass android -keypass android" including double qoute like u said but it replies "The file name,directory name,vlume label syntax in correct"

Comment: C:\Users\Shazar\.android\debug.keystore this is my debug keystore path in eclipse

Comment: sir actually i install the jre7 so when i wrote this command C:\> "C:\Program Files (x86)\java\jre6\bin\keytool.exe" -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\Shazar\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android like u said so it excuted the adroiddebug key certificate fingureprint <SHA1> x:x:x:X:x:x:................wat can i do sir

Comment: I don't know what you mean? If you got the SHA1 fingerprint, then you need to register it, *Registering the Certificate Fingerprint with the Google Maps Service* at the above Google link.

Answer (score 0):

I Accept the @chrkad answer but for generating MD5 certificate, you should always use the keytool.exe located in jdk5 or jdk6(Development kit) folder. jre6 will provide the runtime environment and problems raises when you use MD5 certificate generated by jre keytool to get maps api key. I faced such problem and sharing the same with you.

Comment: sorry sir am not getting ur answer will u elaborate plz seriously sir i am totlly fed up with freaking command line method though i am very passionate devleper but this realy made me insane

Comment: @user1796974 Hey you put keystore path in double quotes and point the keytool which is located in jdk folder. search for keytool in program files,java,jdk,bin folders.